console.log messages are not showing up in pm2 log files
I have made a simple test script:
function tester() {
  console.log('hello there', process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);
  setTimeout(tester, 1000);
}
tester();

My pm2 config file is:
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'tester',
      script: 'node scripts/tester',
    }
  ]
}

I start pm2:
npx pm2 start config.cjs --name tester -i 5 --time

and I see:
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [tester](ids: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
[PM2] [tester](0) ✓
[PM2] [tester](1) ✓
[PM2] [tester](2) ✓
[PM2] [tester](3) ✓
[PM2] [tester](4) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
┌────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ tester    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 73218    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 52.0mb   │ patrick  │ disabled │
│ 1  │ tester    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 73219    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 52.3mb   │ patrick  │ disabled │
│ 2  │ tester    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 73220    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 49.6mb   │ patrick  │ disabled │
│ 3  │ tester    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 73223    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 49.6mb   │ patrick  │ disabled │
│ 4  │ tester    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 73226    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 46.7mb   │ patrick  │ disabled │
└────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

pm2 logs shows:
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:0] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:1] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:0] online
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:1] online
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:2] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:3] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:2] online
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:4] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:3] online
PM2        | 2024-09-23T22:32:29: PM2 log: App [tester:4] online

/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-out-0.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-error-0.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-out-1.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-error-1.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-out-2.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-error-2.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-out-3.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-error-3.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-out-4.log last 15 lines:
/Users/patrick/.pm2/logs/tester-error-4.log last 15 lines:

and my log directory has:
> ls -l .pm2/logs/
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-error-0.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-error-1.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-error-2.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-error-3.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-error-4.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:05 tester-error.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-out-0.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-out-1.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-out-2.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-out-3.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 22:24 tester-out-4.log
-rw-r--r--  1 patrick  staff  0 Sep 23 20:45 tester-out.log

Why are console log statements not getting written to the log files?

It seems that this is a problem with the configuration file name. I've been able to reproduce your issue using the files you provided, and changing the config.cjs to tester.config.js worked.
Here is the relevant line from the documentation:

If you are creating your own configuration file, make sure it ends with .config.js so PM2 is able to recognize it as a configuration file.

With the change above (config.cjs -> tester.config.js), I was able to get the logs to work.

If I don't have a .cjs extension, then it throws an error due to my package being type: "module" and theconfig file having module.exports = ... -- I was getting:  ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope until I renamed to .cjs

This should still work as tester.config.cjs. Keep in mind, you might also want to update the actual config contents to include the file extension for the tester script if you don't use .js there. For example: script: 'node scripts/tester.cjs'. If this does not work, it would be useful if you could share a repository that could be used to reproduce the error. Otherwise, it's hard to tell which parts of your setup could be at fault. Hope this helps!

the scripts/tester file is not a .cjs .. it's using es6 syntax, hence the package.json is type module.

This shouldn't prevent you from setting the script to just the filename then; you could simply use script: './scripts/tester.js'. Are you still seeing problems with logs not showing up (likely due to processes not actually starting correctly)? Can you share your setup, or at least a minimal reproduction example with the changes I suggested? If it's a plain javascript file, you shouldn't have any problems at this point. On the off-chance that you're using TypeScript or something similar that requires transpiling, this would necessitate some extra steps. Please share a repository if possible.
